# Floodplain Delineation using Rasters - ArcGIS/HecRAS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hec-ras

I exported my HecRAS results as GIS format and created from the .sdf file a .xml file with the HecRas extension for ArcGIS.

After that I want to perform

*"Floodplain Delineation using Rasters"*

with the HecRAS extension.

But I got always the same error and don't know how to handle that.

[image: ArcGIS error message]

Comment: It’s been quite sometime since I’ve use HEC-RAS/HEC-geoRAS but perhaps this link would help : https://community.esri.com/thread/60997

Comment: Particularly, Rudy36’s comment about the GRID format requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never gone the way you describe, probably it is just lack of arcgis.

What I do when I need an inundation boundary map is to produce the GIS file(s) directly from Ras Mapper, available as part of HEC-RAS.

In the result tree I add a new results map layer, then I choose an "inundation boundary layer" type and from there, that layer could be exported as a shape file.

[image] 
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: I did it also in this way, but i noticed that error in ArcGIS. At the beginning I followed the HecRAS manuel. The export as Shapefile is my opinion also easier. I just want show that there is a problem in ArcGIS or maybe with the converted .sdf - file. I may sholud that add to my question.